# Conflict between positional_or_keyword_parameters and var_positional_parameters?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just defined a function in the following when I learn about the knowledge about parameter:

```py
>>> def f1(a, b, /, c=0, *args,d, **kw):
    print('a =', a, 'b =', b, 'c =', c, 'args =', args, 'd = ', d, 'kw =', kw)
```

And it seems to be running well in my first try:

```py
>>> f1(1,2,3,*[4,5,6],d=7,e=8)
a = 1 b = 2 c = 3 args = (4, 5, 6) d =  7 kw = {'e': 8}
```

However, when I do modification about the argument for "c", which is known as positional_or_keyword_parameters in python, the running results beyond my expectation.

I trying to run:

```py
>>>f1(1,2,c=3,*[4,5,6],d=7,e=8)
>>>f1(1,2,*[4,5,6],d=7,e=8)
```

In my expectation, the result will be:

```py
a = 1 b = 2 c = 3 args = (4, 5, 6) d =  7 kw = {'e': 8}

a = 1 b = 2 c = 0 args = (4, 5, 6) d =  7 kw = {'e': 8}
```

But the reality is:

```py
>>> f1(1,2,c=3,*[4,5,6],d=7,e=8)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#20>", line 1, in <module>
    f1(1,2,c=3,*[4,5,6],d=7,e=8)
TypeError: f1() got multiple values for argument 'c'

>>> f1(1,2,*[4,5,6],d=7,e=8)
a = 1 b = 2 c = 4 args = (5, 6) d =  7 kw = {'e': 8}
```

Then I look up the python documentation.  What surprised me was that there is not any example codes in python documentation like mine. I mean, the example codes like:

```py
#the define:
    def f(a, b, /, c, d, *, e, f):
    def func(posonly1, posonly2, /, positional_or_keyword): ...
    def func(*args, **kwargs): ...
```

In these case,  the positional_or_keyword_parameters  and the var_positional_parameters cannot be present at the same time.

Is that the truth?The syntax of python does not support that the positional_or_keyword_parameters  and the var_positional_parameters present at the same time？ If it does not, how can I achieve my expectations?

```py
>>> def f1(a, b, /, c=0, *args,d, **kw):
    print('a =', a, 'b =', b, 'c =', c, 'args =', args, 'd = ', d, 'kw =', kw)
    
#my expectations:
>>>f1(1,2,c=3,*[4,5,6],d=7,e=8)
a = 1 b = 2 c = 3 args = (4, 5, 6) d =  7 kw = {'e': 8}
>>>

>>>f1(1,2,*[4,5,6],d=7,e=8)
a = 1 b = 2 c = 0 args = (4, 5, 6) d =  7 kw = {'e': 8}
>>>
```

---

@Programmer:

In your answer, you gave me advice on function definition:

```
def f1(a, b, /, d, *args, c=0, **kw):
```

I see that the parameter *d*  is defined without a default value, but *d* is opposite.  Let us talk about something more interesting about this.

In my opinion,  the level of mastery of a syntax  depends on making it useful, not just using it correctly. I would like to do a split of your codes and ignore some elements, it will like like:

```py
#define f1
def f1(a, b, /, d=0):  #I prefer to do so, defining positional_or_keyword_parameters with default value
    
#define f2
def f2(*args,c) or def f2(*args,c=0) #define keyword_only_parameters with or without default value
```

Function definition like *f1*() is useful, think about the python function *range()*:

```py
#I assume the definition of range() is liking the following
def range(start, /, stop=None, step=1):  #the dedault value is frequently used
    if stop is None:   #use a few tips
        stop = start
        start = 0
    ...    
#I defined the positional_or_keyword_parameters(just "stop" and "step") with default value
#Therefore, I can generate the following instances:

range(10)                 #when I don't need the "stop" and "step", codes can be simple
range(0,10)               #I need "start" and "stop" but not "step", I can still ignore the value of "step"
range(0,10,1)             #I need all of them, however, I can still avoid complex syntax checks

#In short, this parameters definiton() make us more focusing on the polymorphism of functions and generating an instance by a very simple way, rather than doing complex syntax checks again and again

#Imagine this...
def range(start,/,stop=None,step): # define positional_or_keyword_parameters without default value
    ...
    
>>>range(10,step=1)     #I have to write the stupid "step=1" again and again
>>>range(5,step=1)
>>>range(3,step=1)

>>>range(1,10,1)        #I have to write the stupid "1" again and again
>>>range(2,5,1)
>>>range(3,6,1)
```

The situation is reversed when I define the function like *f2()*,  think about the python function *max()*:

```py
#I assume the definition of max() is liking the following
def max(*args,key) or def max(*args,key=abs) :
    ...
#They are all useful
#In this case, max() must receive var_positional_parameters at first, and then use keyword_only_parameters("key" in this case) to achieve the polymorphism of functions. If the keyword_only_parameters without default value, it will make a serious situations that user of max() must explicitly what he/she do with the max(), and still no loss the polymorphism of functions. Relativily, the case  of keyword_only_parameters with default value do more convenience but less strictness.

#example codes
max(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,key=abs)    # *args is so long...  the length of "key=abs" is easy to accept
max(*list)                           # It's convenient
```

Back to the main topic, my question about the definition like:

```py
def f1(a, b, /, c=0, *args,d, **kw):
    ...
    
#  let us ignore irrelevant elements, it will be:
def f1(/, c=0, *args,d):
```

In fact, I loss of interest about it in few hours. The reason is that I can't figure out why I have to define a function like it. Its syntax is correct , but useless at the same time. At least I can't think of any use for it.

A useless syntax ...

Maybe my question is really boring...

Comment: Sorry, but the code you posted is not executable and does not work, because of the slash in `def f1(a, b, /, c=0, *args,d, **kw):`

Comment: @azro "you can't put keywords argument after positional argument" - of course you can, how else would you do it ?!?

Comment: @Programmer About the slash in my function definition, it is a new python syntax in python 3.8. See PEP 570 for a full description.

Comment: @guaiu ah, ok, i didn't know this and couln'd find out by testing because i only have Py3.6 ! Sorry.

Comment: Ok, I think I''m not the right man to answer this ...